# Counting Object Length based on key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I have a JS object/ associative array with some values:

```
var array =[
{val:1,ref:10,rule:100},
{val:1,ref:12,rule:120},
{val:2,ref:13,rule:165},
];
```

And I want to perform a .length, but want to be able to slice based on one of the keys (for instance val == 1). I want the length of values with val 1 rather than the length of the entire object. I have looked through the references material and could not find a satisfactory answer and I am unsure if this is feasible.

```
array.val==1.length = 2
```

Something like that...

Comment: [You're looking for the Array `.filter()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array for elements that match some predicate:

```
var filteredArray = array.filter(function(element) { return element.val == 1 })
filteredArray.length // = 2
```

`filter` applies the callback function to each element in the array, and the new filtered array contains all elements from original array for which the filter callback function returned `true`. Here, the function returns `true` for all elements with a `val` property of `1`.

Comment: That worked much better than the convoluted slice I was trying to use, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `.filter()`:

```
array.filter(function(v){return v.val==1}).length
```